# Aplicaciones o Servicos activos/segundo plano

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio

Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de saber cuando el usuario cierra u pasa a segundo plano una activdad.

Cuando realiza el usuario esta acción para yo cerrar mi aplicación a posterior automaticamente.
Pero no consigo sacar ni los procesos activos, aplicaciones o servicios en cache...

He probado con cosas asi:

```
 public void servicioOnline(){


    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
        String packageClassName = services.get(i).service.getClassName();
        if (packageClassName.equals("nombre_paquete_de_la_otra_apk")) {

            System.out.println("Service Nr. " + i + " :" + services.get(i).service);
            System.out.println("Service Nr. " + i + " package name : " + services.get(i).service.getPackageName());
            System.out.println("Service Nr. " + i + " class name : " + packageClassName);

            //return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("hay problemas...");
        }

    }
    //return false;
}
```

U este otro,pero el context no me valdria porque tendria que ser el de la otra app:

```
    public static boolean verAppEjecutada(final Context context, final String packageName) {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (procInfos != null)
        {
            for (final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : procInfos) {
                if (processInfo.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Puede ser por el propio S.O?¿

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar los métodos nativos de android `onPause()` para cuando tu actividad pierde el foco, `onStop()` para cuando tu actividad pasa a segundo plano, por ejemplo recibes una llamada, y `onDestroy()` para cuando tu aplicación es cerrada. Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación de Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Aquí tienes también un fragmento de código de como sería la implementación

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("ON PAUSE");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("ON STOP");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("ON DESTROY");
}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar. El problema es que el ciclo de la vida solo me serviria en mi propia aplicación y yo quiero interactuar con otra. Porque no creo que tenga forma alguna de utilizar el onPause o onStop de la otra app. Y por el propio sistema, no sé como puedo hacerlo. Si la otra se cierra, quiero cerrar la mia.

Comment: No se si serás capad de acceder a la información del sistema de la pila de tareas de Android desde el contexto de tu propia aplicación, por un tema de permisos y seguridad no creo que sea posible pero me quedo por aquí porque me interesa la respuesta, conservo esta por si a alguien le pudiera ayudar

Comment: Vale, he estado jugando con el onResumen pero necesitaria matar la aplicacion o cerrarla completamente y no sé como.